# How can I redirect http traffic?

Tags: linux, http, proxy

My clients sends requests to http://localhost:80/test/string. However my processing unit is at http://localhost:9080/servlet/Endpoint?req=test.

I want this redirection to take place transparently of the client. My client should take the response from http://localhost:9080/servlet/Endpoint?req=test still believing that the response came from http://localhost:80/test/string.

How can be done? Is it possible to do it using a proxy server?

Comment: What you need is a reverse-proxy, not a redirect.

Answer (score 4):

An other solution is that you setup a reverse proxy with apache with proxy_http module (included by default):

the config file should be something like:

```
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass / http://localhost:9080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9080/
```

Then play with mod_rewrite.

- [reverse proxy with apache](http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies)
- [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: ProxyPass does not work with the Question Mark character. Please bare in mind that the URL is changing not only the port

Comment: I was about to apology, but I've just checked on one of my website where I use a reverse proxy for redmine (I run a standalone redmine server on port 3000). The search works perfectly with myreverse.com/search?q=projectname

Comment: I assume that you are using you string as a pattern and not as a substitution string. I am using ProxyPass pattern subs?q=test and the tomcat returns that %3Fq=test is not found (? is encoded as %3F)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. The ?q is used as a GET argument for the search form, and it works fine.